# How do I fire a click-event in the child-component?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I want to run a function for each of the elements clicked. This is the current situation:

```
<!-- This is the parent-component -->
<template ngFor let-myData [ngForOf]="someData"> 
    <tr [item]="myData" (click)="toggleActive($event)" child-component>
</template>
```

The child-component looks like this:

```
<td>{{ item.data1 }}</td>
<td>{{ item.data2 }}</td>
<td>{{ item.data3 }}</td>
```

Every time I click the `tr`, I want the `toggleActive`-function to fire in the child-component I clicked. At the moment it fires in the parent component. How am I able to make this work the way I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work using  a template variable on the child component and refer to it using this variable:

```
<template ngFor let-myData [ngForOf]="getMyData()"> 
    <tr [item]="myData" #child (click)="child.toggleActive($event)" child-component>
</template>
```